# Method name expected in C#

Tags: c#

So, I am developing an application which is able to drag and drop files into the form and display the information of it into a datagridview. Basically I already got something developed in VB.Net and now I want to upgrade it to C# and make somethings better adding features.

I am stuck at the moment because in VB.Net I have this peace of code

```
Private MeuFicheiro As FileInfo

Private Sub frmMenu_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles cmdEntrar.DragDrop
    Dim file As String = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)(0)

    MyFile = New FileInfo(ficheiro)

    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MyFile.Extension) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

And I trying to use the `Dim file As String = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)(0)` C#, but making some changes of course like this:

`string file = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)(0);` in the form method:

```
private void frmMenu_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string ficheiro = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)(0);

        MeuFicheiro = new FileInfo(ficheiro);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MeuFicheiro.Extension))
        {
            return;
        }
     }
```

But it gives me an error in the `e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)(0)` called Method name

> Method name expected

So do you guys have something to help me solving this error?

Comment: Changing VB.NET to C# is not an upgrade.  It's just a different language.  They both compile to the same IL

Comment: put a ".tostring()" at the end of "e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)(0)" maybe it works.

Answer (score 4):

change from parenthesis to square brackets. In C# square brackets are used for indexing arrays.

Do this:

```
string file = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)[0]; // see square brackets
```

Comment: This does not compile. [DataObject.GetData returns an Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557790(v=vs.110).aspx). Cast it to an indexable collection before accessing it's índex.

Answer (score 3):

If `GetData` returns `IList` then change `e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)(0)` to `e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)[0]`

Comment: You cant do `[0]` on a IEnumerable, however if it is something that implements `IList` you can (Which most collection classes do).

Comment: This does not compile. [DataObject.GetData returns an Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557790(v=vs.110).aspx). Cast it to an indexable collection before accessing it's índex.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two errors on your code:

First, [`DataObject.GetData` returns an Object instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557790(v=vs.110).aspx). You will first need to cast that object to the type you are expecting to be stored on that Drag event.
Then, assuming that the returing type was indeed a collection of Strings, you need to use square brackets ([]) to access the first item.

```
var collection = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as IList<string>;
string ficheiro = collection[0];
```

Note that I casted to `IList<string>`, as that will cover most of C#'s indexable generic collections (array, list, hashSet...).

In the other hand, if that object GetData returns is a string, you should do:

```
string ficheiro = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop).ToString();
```